# TYPO3 form extension - finishers create multiple entries in YAML

Tags: forms, typo3

The form extension in TYPO3
finishers create multiple entries in the YAML file.
Don't know exactly why this happens.

Also got multiple mails for confirmation after sending a form.

```
        defaultValue: ''
        type: Text
        identifier: text-1
        label: Objektname
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            required: required
          validationErrorMessages:
            -
              code: '1221560910'
              message: 'Wir brauchen den Namen des Objektes.'
            -
              code: '1221560718'
              message: 'Wir brauchen den Namen des Objektes.'
            -
              code: '1347992400'
              message: 'Wir brauchen den Namen des Objektes.'
            -
              code: '1347992453'
              message: 'Wir brauchen den Namen des Objektes.'
        validators:
          -
            identifier: NotEmpty
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        type: Text
        identifier: text-2
        label: Anlage
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            required: required
          validationErrorMessages:
            -
              code: '1221560910'
              message: 'Um was für eine Anlage handelt es sich?'
            -
              code: '1221560718'
              message: 'Um was für eine Anlage handelt es sich?'
            -
              code: '1347992400'
              message: 'Um was für eine Anlage handelt es sich?'
            -
              code: '1347992453'
              message: 'Um was für eine Anlage handelt es sich?'
```

Comment: Which TYPO3 version do you use?

Comment: version TYPO3 10.4.16

Comment: Can you please share a short excerpt of those "multiple entries" in YAML and add it as an update to your original question? Thx